Bach's figured bass notation?
In this original Bach manuscript excerpt (from BWV 998), does anyone understand what he's writing along the bottom?  Can it be deciphered as figured bass?


“ Bach uses New German organ tablature towards the end of the Allegro, presumably due to running out of page space” —from https://jonty-dawson.github.io/music-scores/editions/bach-js-bwv998-prelude-fugue-allegro-guitar

That is German organ tablature:

Organ tablature is a form of musical notation used by the north German Baroque organ school, although there are also forms of organ tablature from other countries such as Italy, Spain, Poland, and England. Portions of Johann Sebastian Bach's Orgelbüchlein are written in tablature, as are a great deal of the surviving manuscripts of the organ works of Dieterich Buxtehude and other north German organ composers of the Baroque era.

